# Why does Gradle "Copy" task fail when destination directory has files/directories that have elevated access permissions?

Tags: gradle

When using the Gradle copy task to copy an artefact to a directory that contains other files and/or directories that have access permissions outside of the current users privileges, the gradle task fails.  It seems that Gradle tries to enumerate the contents of the destination directory and when it encounters a file/directory that it cannot read, it fails.  I have a hunch that the up-to-date check attemps to hash the contents and fails when it cannot read a file/directory in the destination directory.  Is my understanding correct?  How can I work around this?  Is it possible to disable the up-to-date check for just the copy task?

## Environment

I'm using Gradle 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

## Backround Story

I came across this challenge / issue while doing a Udemy gradle course. The lecture in particular covered deploying a war file to the Tomcat webapps directory using the Copy task. I'm too lazy to install the Tomcat stack so I spun up a docker image with a mount mapped from my host to the webapps directory inside the container.

The docker container runs the Tomcat process as root user and deploys my war as expected 1st time round. The resultant unpacked directory is owned by `root:root`.

Upon rerunning the gradle build script to redeploy a new/same (doesn't matter/irrelevant) war file it fails.  This is just background as to what lead me here.  Please note that I'm not looking for a better way to setup Tomcat or use Docker.  My experiments/testing has empirically separated Tomcat and Docker from the equation.

All other SO questions related to my errors seem to be MS Windows/Anti-virus related.  I am not using Windows and I do not have an Antivirus installed.

## My gradle.build file

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'war'
}

group = 'com.denofprogramming'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext.tomcatWebapps = "/home/donovanh/fake/"

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies { 
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.3.RELEASE'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.2'
    implementation 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compileOnly "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1"
    testImplementation  'junit:junit:4.11'
}

war {
    archiveName = 'mywebappInitial.war'
}

task deployToWebserver(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'war') {
    from war.archivePath
    into "$tomcatWebapps"
}
```

The important part is (the task in question):

```
task deployToWebserver(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'war') {
    from war.archivePath
    into "$tomcatWebapps"
}
```

## Observations

The Gradle build fails from both Eclipse and the command line.
There are three scenarios:

**Scenario 1**: when the destination directory contains no file/directories with escalated privileges. The task **succeeds**.

In this scenario, the destination directory can contain other files and directories as long as they are not access restricted from the user running the Gradle build, for instance no files owned by `root:root`.

**Scenario 2**: when the destination directory contains a file with  escalated privileges. The tasks fails:

Create a file called `a` with escalated privileges:

```
$ touch a
$ sudo chown root:root a
$ sudo chmod 740 a
$ ls -ltra
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 88 donovanh donovanh 20480 Apr  4 00:36 ..
-rwxr-----  1 root     root         0 Apr  4 01:21 a
drwxrwxr-x  2 donovanh donovanh  4096 Apr  4 01:21 .
```

Run the gradle task:

```
> Task :deployToWebserver FAILED
:deployToWebserver (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.021 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':deployToWebserver' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/home/donovanh/fake/a' as it does not exist.
```

To the contrary of the error, the file `a` does exist, but with the following permisions:

```
-rwxr-----  1 root     root         0 Apr  4 01:21 a
```

**Scenario 3**: when the destination directory contains a directory with  escalated privileges.  The task fails:

Create a directory called `a` with escalated privileges:

```
$ mkdir a 
$ sudo chmod 740 a
$ sudo chown root:root a
```

Run the gradle task:

```
> Task :deployToWebserver FAILED
:deployToWebserver (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.02 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':deployToWebserver' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
> Could not read path '/home/donovanh/fake/a'.
```

I note that the directory and the file scenarios have different error messages - thus making them two separate scenarios.  I assume that the up-to-date checker is trying to enumerate the destination directory to create hashes of the contents.  It fails when it encounters a file or directory that it cannot access.

I have also experimented with using `outputs.upToDateWhen { true }`
and outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

as per:

```
task deployToWebserver(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'war') {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { true/false }
    from war.archivePath
    into "$tomcatWebapps"
}
```

...to no avail.

## Question

How do I copy a file to a directory that contains other non-accessible files and/or directories?